# Capture or take a photo and putting it in a GridView or in a gallery

Tags: android, gridview, camera, gallery, photos

I have already written the code to open the Android camera, take a picture and save it to the phone gallery.

I want to add each picture I take to a GridView of photos, or to a gallery that I want to create:

```
public class Upload extends Activity {
    private static final int IMAGE_CAPTURE = 0;
    private Button startBtn;
    private Uri imageUri;
    private ImageView imageView;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.upload_layout);
    imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
    startBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startBtn);
    startBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startCamera();
        }
    });
}

public void startCamera() {
    Log.d("ANDRO_CAMERA", "Starting camera on the phone...");
    String fileName = "testphoto.jpg";
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION,
            "Image capture by camera");
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
    imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
    startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_CAPTURE);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Log.d("ANDRO_CAMERA","Picture taken!!!");
            imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
        }
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   >
<Button android:text="Start Camera"
    android:id="@+id/startBtn"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</Button>


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</ImageView>

<Gallery
    android:id="@+id/gallery1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```